# Limit user to one comment

Tags: comments

is there a nice function I can use to limit logged in users to one comment per post? I'm setting up a review system and only one review permitted per user. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no such nice function. You have to develop it by yourself.

Comment: @EugeneManuilov - that is what this site is here for! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$args = array(
    'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_id' = 100, // post ID. Can be '$post->ID' depending where you are calling this from
    'count' => true
    );
if(get_comments($args) >= 1){
    echo 'disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

[Function_Reference/get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Based on [AndrettiMilas code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/84974/11761).

Comment: How would I code the '$post->ID' bit? There are many posts so don't think I can use 'post_id' = 100 - I am calling this from comments.php thanks.

Comment: `'post_id' = $post->ID,`

Comment: btw sorry AndrettiMilas for not crediting but I did already find this code and was the last bit I needed.

Answer (score 2):

See if this still works:

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$args = array('user_id' => $current_user->ID);
$usercomment = get_comments($args);
if(count($usercomment) >= 1){
    echo 'disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
?>
```

[My source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/one-comment-per-user-per-post)

Comment: You can use `'count' => true` argument to eliminate `count()` call. If set to `true`, `get_comments()` will return comments count only.

Comment: Thanks AndrettiMilas but this function works only looking at all posts - I need to modify it to only look at the current post? Thanks.